# How to deal with the symbol & in labels or strings in OpenERP?

Tags: xml, forms, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to remove a tab from the standard form of partners. The tab I want to remove is `Sales & Purchases`. I removed each one of their siblings without any problem, but I cannot do the same with this one. And that is because the symbol **&**. I always get an error of `XML invalid architecture`.

I tried with these two lines:

```
<xpath expr="/form//notebook//page[@string='Sales &amp; Purchases']" position="replace"/>
```

And:

```
<xpath expr="/form//notebook//page[@string='Sales & Purchases']" position="replace"/>
```

Always the same error. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: whats the error?try removing double slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will work

Generally, we can use this,

```
<page string="string name" position="replace">
    <!-- here you can define your replace with page -->
</page>
```

For `Sales &amp; Purchases,` As per my knowledge, You should not replace Sales & Purchases tab because in this tab, too many field are configurable. Like you go for a replace problems occurs like:

1. Active, Opt-Out and Receive Messages by Email, these are the use for email template. These are not found if you go for replace page.
2. Some property filed will not get value like Sale Pricelist, Purchase Pricelist, Customer Location and Supplier Location.

As per my advice, Please don't replace this tab.

If you still want than follow this step.

1. Hide Sales & Purchase Tab

   ```
   <page string="Sales &amp; Purchases" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
   </page>
   ```
2. Show your new page.

   ```
   <page string="Internal Notes" position="after">
       <page string="Page Name">
           <!-- put your field -->
       </page>
   <page>
   ```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you! but the result is still the same (Invalid XML for View Architecture!). I am pretty sure that the problem is in those lines because if I remove them, there are no errors. And something about the &, because if I try to remove a sibling page (for example, "Internal Notes"), it works using the same expr: <xpath expr="/form//notebook//page[@string='Internal Notes']" position="replace"/> It also works with <page string="Internal Notes" position="replace"/>

Comment: my code will not give a error, because i tried with it, might be you did wrong things. When above code through will help than we don't need of `<xpath>`. If you want above code example, you can check out `sale_journal` module's `sale_journal_view.xml` file. It will help to you.

Comment: you are right, it is not about the &. I copied and pasted from the module you talked me about above and with position="inside" works. But if I put "replace", it gives an error! Why I cannot remove "Sales & Purchases"?

Comment: got your problem i edited my answer please review that.

Comment: thank you very much! I was made to make disappear the page, so I cannot follow your advice. Making the page invisible is the solution I was looking for. Thank you again for your patience.